# git reset --hard seems to ignore .git/info/exclude

Tags: git

We have a shared directory (call it /shared) that we keep automatically up to date with our master git branch, by running these commands whenever there is a push to master:

```
   git reset --hard HEAD
   git clean -f -d
   git pull
```

This works for the most part. However there is a directory /shared/media that we **don't** want to be touched, even though there is a "media" symlink checked into git.

I've added "media" to .git/info/exclude, but regardless, "git reset --hard HEAD" removes /shared/media and replaces it with the checked in symlink.

Is there any way to get "git reset --hard HEAD" to leave this directory alone, other than e.g. by moving it out of the way beforehand and restoring it afterwards?

Comment: `.gitignore` should work just as well as `.git/info/exclude`, and it is committed to git, this being available to all developers. Any reason why are you changing git repo internals instead?

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh: `.git/info/exclude` is meant to be user editable, it isn't a git internal. It is a legitimate way of ignoring paths that are specific to one particular clone.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Your own answer to this question suggests that committing this info to git is usually more useful. But I agree, that for the limited number of use cases (not sure which) it may make sense to add ignored stuff only to `.git/info/exclude`.

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh: I have a "media" symlink checked in, so normally I don't want to ignore it. I only wanted to ignore it in this *particular* clone, hence the change to .git/info/exclude.

Comment: @JonathanSwartz: OK, that's a valid one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't ignore a path that has actual content stored against it in a git repository. Git will honour changes to the tracked tree. Ignoring only affects attempts to start tracking new content, requiring an `add -f` to actually store new content.

This holds however, if you ignore a path with `.gitignore`, `.git/info/exclude`, or via a `core.excludesfile` configuration.

If you don't want your media directory to be removed by a hard reset, you need to remove the conflicting path from the repository. Other than explicitly resetting only other paths, there is no workaround.

Comment: Actually, it can be done with `git update-index` (see my answer)

Answer (score 8):

`git update-index --skip-worktree <file>` should do the trick (see similar question:  [git update-index --assume-unchanged and git reset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6104072/278488))