# GIT Ignore already commited files using exclude for local changes

Tags: git

I cloned the remote repository which is having three files

```
file1.txt 
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

changes are made locally in my machine into file3.txt. I don't want the changes to go into remote repo and vice versa.

I read that using .gitignore it is not possible to ignore the already commited and tracked file.

I decided to use .git/info/exclude file with the following line

**exclude file**

```
file3.txt
```

But still changes made in file3.txt are shown as unstaged file. I want this file3.txt to be ignored in commit and staging and also need to prevent file3.txt to update from remote repo

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: `.git/info/exclude` works identically to `.gitignore` files, just that the former doesn’t need to be within the working directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I read that using .gitignore it is not possible to ignore the already commited and tracked file.

It is, with the `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude`.

You just need to record the deletion of that file first.

```
git rm --cached file3.txt
```

As soon as it is deleted (from the cache only, not from the hard drive), a `git status` should not show it (since it is already in the `.gitignore`)

See "[“`git rm --cached x`” vs “`git reset head — x`”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5800164/6309)": "cache", also called "index" or "staging area", removes the file from index alone and keeps it in your working copy.

`file3.txt` will no longer be versionned in the repo.
And that will propagate to other clones once that deletion will have been committed and push.

---

If you only need to [ignore the file locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14462290/6309) for a while, you can try instead:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- file3.txt
```

Note: that doesn't involve `.gitignore` at all.

To stop locally ignoring changes:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged -- file3.txt
```

Comment: Thanks For the help.will using this command affect the remote repo's file.txt? Please help me understand what is cache is doing here?

Comment: @MohamedHussain cache, or index, is where you are preparing your next commit. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. One more doubt Will running the comment affect other teammates file3.txt. i don't want to modify anything in central remote repo or in others file3.txt.

Comment: if want to do this for entire folder and its content instead of single file file3.txt, how to do it?

Comment: @MohamedHussain yes, it will affect other repos once you have committed and push the deletion of file3.txt

Comment: i don't want that to happen, i am changing file3.txt  for my own test purpose, if it is deleted in other's repo if i pushed then it will affect the project. is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: @MohamedHussain I just edited the answer to indicate an alternative method.

Comment: Thanks for your patience help, i am new to this GIT Please don't mind if i ask some silly questions to you. 
Do I need to run this "git update-index --assume-unchanged [<file>...]" every time i start working on the Git repo? or one time is enough.In the given link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/git-ignore-files-only-locally/14462290#14462290 flag -- is not preceded before the file name is it correct? How to ignore a folder completely since i need to ignore locally multiple files

Comment: @MohamedHussain one time is enough, unless you reset (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8047030/6309) or you check out another branch (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9816844/6309)

Comment: @MohamedHussain For ignoring a folder that way, try `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged -- afolder/` (note the final '`/`'). If it doesn't work, then you will have to do it on all files in the folder: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12288918/6309

Comment: @MohamedHussain the double hyphen (`--`) is just here to separate the command and options from the arguments (files or folder): see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309

Comment: Thanks for your patience help, i tried now it is working good. I learnt lot from this one question. once again thanks Vonc

Comment: @MohamedHussain did `git update-index --assume-unchanged -- afolder/` (with the final '`/`') worked?

Comment: I tried that but Git giving me the message "Ignoring path afolder/", but files are still in unstaged status.

Comment: @MohamedHussain ok. At least http://stackoverflow.com/a/12288918/6309 should work.

Comment: It is working after did as in SO post above. but how to undo this command git ls-files -z | xargs -0 git update-index --assume-unchanged?

Comment: @MohamedHussain same command, with  `--no-assume-unchanged` instead of `--assume-unchanged`.

Answer (score 0):

edit the .gitignore file adding the line:
file3.txt

Comment: the .gitignore file itself is tracked and i don't want to include the file3.txt in .gitigore, I made changes for my local alone in file3.txt, if i add in .gitignore in other teammates clone's also this file is excluded. I don;t want it to happen ,more over i read in net that it is not possible to ignore the tracked file using .gitignore