# git commit config on initial commit but never again?

Tags: git

I have started to use git for my projects, when I create a project it has a config folder containing configuration files:

```
application/config/config.php
application/config/database.php
application/config/routes.php
```

When I first commit I want these files (with their defaults) to be committed, so they exist in the repository as the "default" configurations and if I clone to repository I get these files. When I update them to contain my configuration variables (for the version I'm developing on) I don't want them to be updated in the repository, I want them to remain in their default state in the repository.

I have tried first committing them in their default state and then adding them to my .gitignore file, like so:

```
application/config/*
```

Now when I commit my configuration files aren't committed (yay!) however the original defaults disappear, the folder application/config/ no longer exists in my repository.

I assume I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm very inexperienced with git.

How can I commit the configuration files on my first commit but never again **with** them remaining in the repository in their default state?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could, once versioned, update their index:

```
 git update-index --assume-unchanged application/config/config.php
```

Or you could even update the index more permently:

```
 git update-index --skip-worktree application/config/config.php
```

(as show in "[`git update-index --assume-unchanged` and `git reset`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104072/git-update-index-assume-unchanged-and-git-reset)")

---

The other solution is to *not* version those final config file (since their content may vary as you pointed out), but to use a [filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728):

[image: filter driver]

You would versioned:

- template files (`application/config/config.tpl`)
- config value files (one default, and other for your different environments)
- a script able to recognize the content of a config file (since [it won't have its path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059326/git-equivalent-of-subversions-url-keyword-expansion/2059393#2059393)) and generate the final config files according to the current environment.

Comment: Thank you, the worktree command worked perfectly, I'll look at the second solution as something for my long term git usage. Thanks!