# Is there a hook on git for post-reset?

Tags: git, hook, reset

I have some local files that all developers have to change. I marked the files as "assume unchanged" but that doesn't keep them from changing when doing a reset. Is there a hook on git that's executed after git reset?

If not, does anybody have a suggestion on how to handle this situation?

Comment: There is no "reset" hook, but see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6104072/1256452

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a list of [Git hooks here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html):

- applypatch-msg
- pre-applypatch
- post-applypatch
- pre-commit
- prepare-commit-msg
- commit-msg
- post-commit
- pre-rebase
- post-checkout
- post-merge
- pre-receive
- update
- post-receive
- post-update
- pre-auto-gc
- post-rewrite

There is no `post-reset` hook among them.

Answer (score -3):

In case it help, post-checkout seems to be triggered after a reset.

The 3rd param of that trigger would probably allow you to do what you want.

E.g.:

```
#!/bin/sh


if [ "$3" -eq "0" ]
then
    echo "$3 indicates whether the checkout was a branch checkout (changing branches, flag=1) or a file checkout (retrieving a file from the index, flag=0)"
fi
```

Comment: No, post-checkout is not triggered after reset