# Running TypeScript Compile After Source Control File Changes

Tags: git, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I've installed the TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015 tools and the compile is wicked fast (compared to my old Gulp process). I have compile on save setup in the tsconfig file and that all works great!

However, if I undo a change from source control, it doesn't seem to trigger the compile the way Ctrl+S does. Is there any ways to make VS kick off a file save on a file that was changed by source control?

Comment: "if I undo a change from source control" you mean a revert, rest etc?

Comment: @ParvSharma See the first link in my answer: it shows exactly what "Undo Changes" means in Visual Studio.

Comment: @JimBrown : does a raw `tsc --watch` correctly detects that files have changed on disk ?

Comment: @LeGEC I just tried it and tsc watch sees the change, but Visual Studio doesn't recompile it.

Comment: When I say Undo, I'm referring the the Visual Studio 2015 Undo Change option in the Changes UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that there are 3 different way to "undo a change" in source control: See "[Undo changes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/undo)"

> - Discard uncommitted changes to a file, bringing the file back to the version in the last commit.
> - Reset your local branch to a previous commit.
> - Revert changes pushed to a remote branch and shared with others.

There is [no git hook for post-reset action](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18645512/6309).
(Even though [Visual Studio 2017 did introduce client-side Git hook support](https://andrewlock.net/git-integration-improvements-in-visual-studio-2017/#usinggithooksinvisualstudio2017))

That leaves you with some kind of [service hook](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/get-started), but they are on the server side (for an upstream Visual Studio Online project)

What *might* work if is your reset/undo affect the active document.
In that case, you can use the `DocumentEvents` to trigger a typescript compilation.
It is not a complete solution, but a starting point.

Comment: As stated in my question, I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I am selecting the file in the Changes window and hitting Undo. I have no idea what VS 2015 does under the covers to accomplish that.

Comment: Having the document open and active during the Undo doesn't make any difference, so that won't work unfortunately.

Comment: @JimBrown I understand. I tried to outline the different options,  but I didn't find a clear way to do what you are after, which is what my answer points out.

Comment: So there is no way to do it. Gotta love VS TypeScript compiler. What trash.